# Turning on document library versioning with existing documents

Tags: document-library, versioning

I have a document library with documents already inside, I have turned on "Create major and minor (draft) versions" and enabled the version number in the view.

All the documents default to a version of 1.0, is there anyway to make them default to a minor version instead, e.g. 0.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Documents uploaded to the library will receive version 0.1

You can use the Item Contextual Menu or Ribbon Button "Unpublish" to reset it from 1.0 to 0.1 but you have to do this per item.

Depending on how many documents you have, you might want to just export all the documents, clear the folder and re-copy them back as 0.1

Test it on a different library first.